# php - Dependency injection

Tags: php, dependency-injection

Let's consider an application that searches in a database of books and authors and that writes into a database log every submitted search query.

In this case if I'm correct we should have 4 classes: Books (with something like searchBooks()), Authors (searchAuthor()), Database (executeSelect(), executeInsert()) and Logger (writeDatabaseLog()).

The dependencies should be like:

- Books

  - Database (needed to search)
  - Logger (needed to write log)
- Authors

  - Database (needed to search)
  - Logger (needed to write log)
- Logger

  - Database (needed to write records)

What is the best way to create a Dependency Injection Container for an application like this?

Comment: I'm afraud that's too opinion based for SO. There are so many possibilities.....not even thinking about starting the discussion if you really need a database class. And if a logger should be a singleton. And database only static (therefore not injected)

Comment: Thank you, and yes, I definitely need a database class that needs to be the same in every class that needs it. This is just a simplified version of an application I will be working on. I built a Container class that register classes with a register($class) method (it puts them in a private array property of the container) and give them with a get($ClassName) method, but I don’t know if it’s a good approach.

Comment: my Log is static, my database class is an instance (and has several sublclasses), my Api class is a singleton. All this is for my situation, my needs, just the way I thought it'll be ok. There can't be a 'right' answer to your question. Primaly Opinionated.

Comment: I understand what you’re saying. I really thought that there would be a “right” approach, like a “best practice”. Based on your approach, Log could really be static (can I inject the Database class in it?), Database should be an instance so I could connect to different databases with different instances. Thank you for your time.